# Change print $node_url To a Link Fields Value

Tags: views

Hello i would like to change the destination of a url in a node.tpl (in a view) from this-

```
<a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>">
```

to something like this-

```
<a href="[field_viewslink]">
```

where the field viewslink is a link field in the node itself.

I know i could do it if the view used fields but it doesnt its using a content teaser.

Anyone got any advice?

Thanks

sites/all/themes/other_sub/templates/nodes/node--view--portfolio-block.tpl.php

```
<li class="<?php print str_replace(',-', ' ', str_replace(' ', '-',strip_tags(render($content['field_portfolio_category'])))); ?>">
    <?php print render($content['field_portfolio_image']); ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php print render($content['field_viewslink']); ?>">
          <span class="center">
              <h4 class="heavy remove-bottom"><?php print $title; ?></h4>
              <p><?php print strtolower(render($content['field_portfolio_category'])); ?></p>
          </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got there with this

```
<a href="<?php print strip_tags(render($content['field_viewslink'])); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a field with in the node then you should be able to use the `$node` object.

The object contains all the fields associated with the node.

if you are not sure of the name of the field then you could try to print the object using the `print_r` function.

You could also try try the `$content` object which contains the fields as well.

```
print render($content['field_viewslink']);
```

That should render the variable.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys. I think Mohammed's way is more like the way that i am used to. I will edit my original post to put in the code i have now (which still links to the node funniliy enough)

Comment: Could you check the content of the $node variable by using print_r may be it will give you some clue.

Comment: ive added it to my pag.tpl whichy you can see here mohammed http://islifeshit.com/ but nothing showing. If they had simply done it with fields and not using teaser conent id be ok.

Comment: sorry the block view wasnt showing to non regustered guests. it is now. Ive tried prin r and devel and everything. It SHOULD work as it is but for some reason it isnt. im all drupal depressed. been at ut for 7 days solid. i give up for now i think :(

Comment: mmmm well ive finally got it down to showing an array. the field is being loaded in the view mohammed. Ach ill get there yet. Maybe ill go for a walk around the park to get my mind back

Comment: you should add the print_r statement in the node--view--portfolio-block.tpl.php. this will show the value in the variable and you can get the exact variable to print.

Comment: I am having a bit of problems with the print r statement Mohammed but ive got Devel on the case and i think this does the same thing no? In my content type i have added a field 'field_internal_link'. Due to the bizarre way the themer has made up the node.tpl i cant use the content type display pages for fields to show up in the node. i have added <?php print render($content['field_internal_link']); ?> to the node.tpl. When i visit the view and look at the devel side of things my field isnt being rendered or loaded. im a little lost now. Sorry Rupesh i dont think yousuggestion would work in thi

Comment: in this user case. my node.tpl looks like this though http://pastebin.com/wpd1dTzm

Comment: a wait a sec....silly old me put it in the wrong node.tpl. lets see.....ive nearly got it working. you can see it here http://islifeshit.com the node--view--portfolio-block.tpl.php i have is http://pastebin.com/mf7wPE7H not only will i need to hide the link i need it somehow to be in the url part. Anyone? tx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) function to modify value of node.tpl.php

e.g:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
//$variables['node_url'] = url($uri['path'], $uri['options']);
$variables['node_url'] = url(YOUR-CUSTOM-URL);
}
```